# Is it possible to control which macros are imported from a module?

Tags: rust

The documentation says that if a `macro_use` attribute is on an `extern crate` statement, then it can specify which macros are imported like this: `#[macro_use(macro1, macro2)]`. Is there any way to do this for `mod` statements?

Comment: Why do you need this functionality?

Comment: Out of the box solution: Don't export macros you don't want OR make fine-grained modules and only import the ones you want.

Comment: @Shepmaster I have a macro called `html` and it is in the file `html_macro.rs`. I have `#[macro_use] mod html_macro;` in my `main.rs` file. The `html` macro requires another macro `html_inner` to work, which is defined in the same file. I want the other code in my application to be able to use the `html` macro but I don't want the `html_inner` macro to be visible outside of the `html_macro.rs` file.

Comment: That's not how macros work. If `html!` invokes `html_inner!`, then both macros need to be in scope when `html!` is invoked.